# How do I activate a cell in a uitableview based on value of another?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view.  Each of 3 cells calls a picker view.  But I want the third cell to control the appearance of a fourth cell.  If the user picks a value of "1" for cell 3, then I want cell #4 to be available or activated to the user to pick an additional value.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean "calls a picker view"?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this. When you select a row in the picker

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

   // Check proper condition and do accordingly
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
```

It is just an idea you need to elaborate it.

**Edit**
One tricky solution
You want to grey out the last cell. It is pretty easy just check a solution in **numberOfRowsInSection**

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if(showLastCell)
     {
       return 4;
     }
   return 3;
 }
```

This will grey out the last cell if the condition is false.

When the picker selected make the condition true(`showLastCell = YES`) and reload the tableView

```
  [self.tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was thinking. But my doubt is, how do I make a greyed out cell become active or ungreyed?  Better yet, can I grey out a cell until the value returned by the picker is equal to, say, "3", so that the greyed out cell can then be ungreyed?

Answer (score 0):

Yup it can be done. you just need to access it in didSelectMethod.

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 3){
       NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
     //if you want to control only the appearance of the cell
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idx];
    // do something with cell
    // [cell setNeedsLayout]// call to update the cell and comment out self tableview: call
      [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:idx];

  }
  else if(indexPath.row == 4){
      NSLog(@">>>clicked");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes, but how would I "activate" or "insert" a new cell based on this?  Iow, I want to have a cell greyed out and ungrey it based on a click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the question. Even so, perhaps this can help.

Reload the cell at a particular index path using [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a). Pass in an array containing a single index path for the first parameter in your case. Make an appropriate implementation of [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) in your table's data source.